# What is the difference between this.state.function and this.function in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning the concept of States in React. I am trying to understand the difference between using this.handleChange, and this.state.handleChange.

I would be grateful if someone could explain to me, the exact difference between the two, and why would this.state.handleChange not work?

```
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      inputValue: event.target.value
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
       <div>
        < GetInput input={this.state.inputValue} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
        { /* this.handleChanges, and this.state.handleChanges */ }
         < RenderInput input={this.state.inputValue} />
       </div>
    );
  }
};

class GetInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Get Input:</h3>
        <input
          value={this.props.input}
          onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

class RenderInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Input Render:</h3>
        <p>{this.props.input}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can technically call `this.state.handleChange` so long as you add `handleChange` in your state.

But it doesn't really make sense since you don't want React to keep a track of it, and it will probably not change (unless you are doing some `clever` tricks).

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      handleChange: e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("this.state.handleChange");
      }
    };
  }
```

One would normally declare a member function in a class.

```
  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("this.handleChange");
  };
```

Here is the full working code
*(working demo available on [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zq376znzp4)).*

[image: Edit zq376znzp4]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      handleChange: e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("this.state.handleChange");
      }
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("this.handleChange");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <button onClick={this.handleChange}>this.handleChange</button>
        <button onClick={this.state.handleChange}>
          this.state.handleChange
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Is there any scenario where it would be preferred to use this.state.handleChanges instead?

Comment: I can't think of any real-world use case. But It's possible to `inject` a function and override the state method with a prop `state = { handleChange: this.prop.handleChange }`.  But you'd still never save that prop as a state but just call the injected method as `this.prop.handleChange`.  You can pass `handleChange` from instantiating class, say `App` like `render() { return <MyApp handleChange={this.handleChange} }` where `this.handleChange` is declared in `App`

Comment: @Sung I've seen such scenario with the use of the Context API. You create a Context Provider which has its own state and private methods, but you expose those by binding them to the state which is then passed down as a whole to the consumer.

Comment: @Chris. Thanks mate 

Comment: Thats a valuable stuff @SungKim

Answer (score 2):

When you say `this.state.something` this means something is in the state field of the class. When you say `this.someFunction` this means something is in the class itself. `this` here is pointing out our class.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    something: "Something",
  }
  
  someFunction = () => console.log(this.state.something);
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.someFunction}>Click</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

So, you can't use `this.state.handleChange` since there is no `handleChange` in the state. It is a function belongs to the class. This is why we use `this.handleChange`.

Answer (score 1):

you can store a function in state

```
constructor(super){
super(props)
 this.state = {
  generateANumber: () => this.setState({ number: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) }),
  number: 0
 }
}
```

then if you want to call it in your render method

```
render() {
 return <p> {this.state.number} <button onClick={() => this.state.generateANumber()} Press Me To Generate A New Number </button> </p> 
}
```

This is the concept of storing a function in state. This.function just means the function belongs to that class so you can use it using the `this` keyword.